# Почему цикл не прекращается командной break?

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется задание, в котором нужно проверить каждый массив на упорядоченность строго на убывание. Если он упорядочен - `true`.

почему на `matrix[0][1]` , когда идет сравнение с `matrix[0][2]` - цикл не прекращает свое сравнение, а проверяет дальше следующие массивы `{5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}}`. Хотя я специально обозначил, что в случае нарушения убывания значений элементов массива - пойдет `break`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int[][] matrix = {{3, 2, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}};
        int bolshe;
        boolean isSortedDescendant = false;

        if (matrix.length == 0){
            isSortedDescendant = true;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                bolshe = matrix[i][0];
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length-1; j++) {
                    if (bolshe > matrix[i][j+1]) {
                        bolshe = matrix[i][j+1];
                        isSortedDescendant = true;
                    } else if (bolshe <= matrix[i][j+1]){
                        isSortedDescendant = false;
                        break;    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(isSortedDescendant);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Эту информацию можно найти в любой статье, посвящённой `break`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что у вас вложенный цикл.
При использовании внутри набора вложенных циклов оператор `break` будет выходить только из самого внутреннего цикла.
Для решения данной задачи стоит воспользоваться метками `break outer;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
int[][] matrix = {{3, 2, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {8, 7, 6}};
    int bolshe;
    boolean isSortedDescendant = false;

    if (matrix.length == 0){
        isSortedDescendant = true;
    } else {
    outer: // Ставим метку
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            bolshe = matrix[i][0];
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length-1; j++) {
                if (bolshe > matrix[i][j+1]) {
                    bolshe = matrix[i][j+1];
                    isSortedDescendant = true;
                } else if (bolshe <= matrix[i][j+1]){
                    isSortedDescendant = false;
                    break outer; // Переходим к метке


                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(isSortedDescendant);
   }
```

Замечание: Break не проектировался в качестве нормального средства завершения цикла. Эту цель обслуживает условное выражение заголовка цикла. Оператор break следует использовать для прерывания цикла только тогда, когда возникают некоторые специальные ситуации.